# Single Variable in Multiple Places Exponent/Logarithm

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

How on Earth do I solve for $x$ when:
$2 = x^{x-1}$
?
I know that the obvious solution is $2$, & that the other is approximately $.346323362$, but  want an exact way to write it, i.e. $\ln(2)/2$ or something like that. I have scoured the internet & have found nothing helpful so far.

Comment: It can’t be expressed in terms of elementary functions, but you could use the [Lambert W function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Do you know how to solve with that?